# Testing for Inequality Doesn't Work

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

```
CONFIRM=""

echo "Do you want to backup your home directory? Please enter y|Y or n|N"

read CONFIRM;
if [[ "$CONFIRM" != "Y" ]] || [[ "$CONFIRM" != "y" ]]; then
  echo "The backup will not run. Aborting now..."
else
  echo "The backup will run now. Backing up to $DEST"
  # more code
fi
```

Whenever I enter "y" or "Y", the condition under `else` should be executed. Instead, the condition under `if` gets executed no matter what I enter. I've tried multiple combinations of square brackets and quoting I can think of, but nothing works. Why doesn't the `else` branch correctly execute?

Comment: I will provide a solution that is a key press y/n with case insensitive when I am in front of a computer shortly

Comment: The test is probably simpler as `if [[ $CONFIRM != [Yy] ]]`.  `[Yy]` means *either* y or Y (single characters).  You don't need quotes around the variable name inside `[[` in this context, even if it contains embedded whitespace (other contexts you do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
[[ "$CONFIRM" != "Y" ]] || [[ "$CONFIRM" != "y" ]]
```

means "`$CONFIRM` isn't `Y` *or* `$CONFIRM` isn't `y`". That is always guaranteed to be true:

- if `$CONFIRM` is `Y`, then it's not `y`, so the second option is true
- if `$CONFIRM` is `y`, then it's not `Y`, so the first option is true
- if `$CONFIRM` is anything else, then both options are true

To fix this, you need to use `&&` ("and") instead of `||` ("or"):

```
[[ "$CONFIRM" != Y ]] && [[ "$CONFIRM" != y ]]
```

which, by [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), is equivalent to this:

```
! { [[ "$CONFIRM" = Y ]] || [[ "$CONFIRM" = y ]] ; }
```

Comment: The confusion between 'and' and 'or' is precisely what the problem was. Now that I'm looking at my script again, I can see why I was getting incorrect output.

Answer (score 1):

If we look closely at the prompt *"Please enter **y | Y or n | N**"*, then there is a third case missing, that handles invalid input. Together with [@cdarke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50780159/testing-for-inequality-doesnt-work#comment88570156_50780159)'s answer, this results e.g. in the following short condition:

```
CONFIRM=""

echo "Do you want to backup your home directory? Please enter y|Y or n|N"

read CONFIRM;
if [[ "$CONFIRM" = [Yy] ]]; then
  echo "The backup will run now. Backing up to $DEST"
  # more code
elif [[ "$CONFIRM" = [Nn] ]]; then
  echo "The backup will not run. Aborting now..."
else
  echo "Wrong Input. Please enter y|Y or n|N."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example, I ensure we don't continue until we get specifically y/n/q as inputs. using -p -n1 removes the need to press enter. In summary: a case statement, reads the one keypress, lowercase checking etc ... This example allows for yes/no or quit.

```
typeset confirm=''
while true; do
    read -p "Select (y/n/q) ?" -n1 confirm
    case ${confirm,,} in
        y|n|q) break;;
        *) echo "Answer y for yes / n for no  or q for quit.";;
    esac
done
echo -e "\nAnswer = $confirm" ;sleep 2

if [[ "${confirm,,}" == "q" ]] ; then
        echo "OK Quitting.."
        exit 0
fi

if [[ "${confirm,,}" == "y" ]] ; then
        echo "Continuing ..."
else
        echo "No? Do something else etc.. "
fi
```